# Setting application fee with Omnipay/Stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-connect, omnipay

I am using Laravel Omnipay and Omnipay/Stripe.  I am trying to set an application fee ([Stripe resource](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees)) to be collected but after I fill in card data and post to my controller I get this error:

> InvalidRequestException in AbstractRequest.php line 213: The source
>   parameter is required

According to [Omnipay/Stripe](http://omnipay/stripe/src/Message/AuthorizeRequest.php) I am allowed to pass the `application_fee` [(AbstractRequest reference)](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe/blob/5a52082bf3cb93066c2e318ad6034d3d64f575e3/src/Message/AuthorizeRequest.php#L231) as a `transactionFee` but it is not working

**My controller:**

```
$payment = $request->amount;
$gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe');
$gateway->setApiKey($company->settings()->get('gateway_keys')['Stripe']['test_secret']);

// Send purchase request
$response = $gateway->purchase(
    [
        'amount' => $payment,
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'token' => $request->stripeToken,
        'transactionFee' => 100,
        'stripe_account' => $company->settings()->get('gateway_keys')['Stripe']['account_id']
        //'card' => $formData
    ]
)->send();
```

How do I get it where I can charge an application fee?

Comment: Go into your Stripe account and look at the logs. They will give you a better idea why your request failed.

Comment: I don't think it makes it to stripe to be logged, error happens before the request is made

Comment: I'm not familiar with the lib you're using, but I am familiar with Stripe and Connect. I re-read the error and it says 'source is required'. The source is the charge token, which is shown in your array as 'token'. I couldn't say if the key 'token' is correct syntax in the lib you're using, but that error tells me that $request->stripeToken may be null.

Comment: That was indeed my problem with the above error, no more working late at night :)

Comment: I have the same issue with an opensource project I use and which use omnipay, when trying to make it work with connect. I don't have any `token` passed though